# why is my grid content not wrapping text, or showing ellipsis?

Tags: css

I am having trouble getting long-string text to wrap &/or show ellipsis.  It's kind of like a table, but really it's 2 columns with rows.

I have tried messing around with the `.line-flex` and the `.long-text-maybe` classes, but no success.

Is there some sort of conflict between the grid wrapper & flex contents?

```css
.box {
  width: 50%;
}

.gridwrapp {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.line-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="gridwrapp">
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Reservation ID: </p>
  <p class="long-text-maybe">982398</p>
</div>
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Item Name: </p>
  <a href="/items/342342">2020 Ram Promaster 1500 HR 136 WB Custom</a>
</div>
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Name: </p>
  <p class="long-text-maybe">Kim Bob</p>
</div>
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Location: </p>
  <p class="long-text-maybe">Really long name in a place far far away</p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call directly to the children containing the text elements for `ellipsis` to take effect. Check out the CSS changes I made.

```css
.box {
  width: 50%;
}

.gridwrapp {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.line-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.line-flex > p, a {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="gridwrapp">
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Reservation ID: </p>
  <p class="long-text-maybe">982398</p>
</div>
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Item Name: </p>
  <a href="/items/342342">2020 Ram Promaster 1500 HR 136 WB Custom</a>
</div>
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Name: </p>
  <p class="long-text-maybe">Kim Bob</p>
</div>
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Location: </p>
  <p class="long-text-maybe">Really long name in a place far far away</p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will have to use `flex-wrap: wrap;` to get your text to wrap automatically. This includes getting rid of the `white-space: nowrap;` on your `line-flex` so that the text can wrap.

**See here:**

```css
.box {
  width: 50%;
}

.gridwrapp {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.line-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="gridwrapp">
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Reservation ID: </p>
  <p class="long-text-maybe">982398</p>
</div>
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Item Name: </p>
  <a href="/items/342342">2020 Ram Promaster 1500 HR 136 WB Custom</a>
</div>
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Name: </p>
  <p class="long-text-maybe">Kim Bob</p>
</div>
<div class="line-flex">
  <p>Location: </p>
  <p class="long-text-maybe">Really long name in a place far far away</p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah this for sure work.  And it seems like there's something else conflicting inside my code itself.  I'll keep digging around.

Comment: marked as answer still :)

Comment: @PhilLucks hopefully next time I am worthy... I gave you +1

Comment: @PhilLucks can I suggest just add the flexbox to your parent? I feel this will solve your conflicts.